# How to read data using OData service from Dynanic crm in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, odata, dynamics-crm

I am totally new in dynamic crm and i have to retrieve data from crm using odata in windows phone. i have written code but its giving error.
private cresol1Context entities;

```
   private readonly Uri OdataUri = new Uri("https://cresol1.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/");

    private DataServiceCollection<Lead> lstcustomer;




    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        entities = new cresol1Context(OdataUri);
        //  entities.Credentials == new NetworkCredential(("mspnitesh@cresol1.onmicrosoft.com",         "********", "cresol1.crm5.dynamics.com");
        //entities.AccountSet.First();

        lstcustomer = new DataServiceCollection<Lead>(entities);

        //query
        var result = from r in entities.LeadSet  select r;

        lstcustomer.LoadCompleted += lstcustomer_LoadCompleted;
        lstcustomer.LoadAsync(result);

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    void lstcustomer_LoadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (lstcustomer.Continuation != null)
            {

                lstcustomer.LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = lstcustomer;

            }
        }

        else {

            MessageBox.Show("Some error"+e.Error.Message," error",MessageBoxButton.OK);

        }
    }
```

when we run this application we get this error
the response payload is a not a valid response payload. please make sure that the top level element is a valid atom element or belongs to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' namespace.

any help .?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you use wrong authentication approach. Recheck following article that describes how that could be done - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481603.aspx